# Calculating probability of a bivariate distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Calculate the probability that $$P(X\le 250)$$
Suppose that (
X,Y
) has a bivariate distribution uniformly on the circle
$x^2+y^2≤2000^2$.

So far I have integrated the bivariate density from $-/+\sqrt{2000-x^2}$ and now I am considering integrating again except this time I will be integrating from -2000 to 250. Are these bounds for the second integral correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach - without calculus.
R=2000, u=250, v=u/R.  $P(X\le u)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{arcsin(v)+v\sqrt{1-v^2}}{\pi}$.

The first term is $P(X\le 0)$.

The other two terms come from dividing the area of $0\lt x \lt u \ and\ y\gt 0$ into two parts and then multiplying by 2 to include negative y contribution.

The area division is by a radius ending at the point on the circle where x=u.  To the right of this radius is a right triangle with area=$u\sqrt{R^2-u^2}/2$.  To the left of this radius is a sector with area=$R^2arcsin(v)/2$.  To get $P(0\lt X\lt u)$, add these two terms, multiply by 2 and then divide by the area of the circle $\pi R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Direct approach.  Let R=2000, u=250.  Then the area of the part of the circle for $0\le x\le 250$ can be the sum of 2 terms, $A=2u\sqrt{R^2-u^2}$ and $B=2\int_\sqrt{R^2-u^2}^R\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}dxdy$.  Therefore $P(X\le 250)=\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{A+B}{\pi R^2}$. The one half is $P(X\le 0)$.  You do the arithmetic.